# How can I catch form on a user control ِDLL in C#?

Tags: c#

I made a UserControl ِDLL that will be called by another program, I want to get the parent form for which I used below scripts but all of them return null, How can I get the form that calls my DLL?

```
if(Parent != null){
    Form form1 = this.FindForm(); //null
    Form form2 = (Form) this.Parent.Parent; //null
    Form form3 = (Form) this.ParentForm;//null

    UserControl parent = (UserControl)this.Parent;

    Form form4 = (Form) parent.FindForm(); //null
    Form form5 = (Form) parent.ParentForm;//null
    this.Parent.GetType(); // return a class inherited from UserControl
}
```

Comment: Can you please fix your question as it isn't very understandable. Also please provide a code sample where it is breaking, how you are utilizing the code.

Comment: Why does your user control need to know about it's parent ? If it requires certain information then it should expose methods / properties that the owner should call.